# In vue 3, can I use both v-model:custom-property and @update:custom-property?

Tags: events, vuejs3, v-model

I want to update a custom property value inside a child component,
and also want to get event whenever the value is changed.

So, I tried both `v-model:` and `@update:`, like this.

```
<CustomName v-model:custom-name="name"
            @update:custom-name="nameChanged"/>
```

```
// CustomName.vue
<script>
export default {
  name: 'CustomName',
  props: {
    customName: String
  },
  emits: ['update:customName'],
  
  setup(_, {emit}) {
    const customNameChanged = (event) => {
      emit('update:customName', event.target.value)
    }
    return {
      customNameChanged
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <input :value="customName" @change="customNameChanged"/>
</template>
```

I expected that `name` is changed and `nameChanged` is called,
but `name` is not changed.

I tried some cases at the [vue sfc playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

The result is,

(1) When I use camelCase, value is updated and method is called.

```
<CustomName v-model:customName="name4"
            @update:customName="nameChanged"/>
```

(2) But when I use kebab-case, value is NOT changed and method is called.

```
<CustomName v-model:custom-name="name3"
            @update:custom-name="nameChanged"/>
```

(3) Without `@update:`, camelCase and kebab-case are worked well.

```
<CustomName v-model:custom-name="name1"/>
<CustomName v-model:customName="name2"/>
```

Is this right? Is it illegal to use `v-model` with `@update`? Or should I use camelCase?